# Reposition elements in html with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't figure how to achieve this in the best way:
Let's say I have:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

And I want to move every 'child' right after it's parent.

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
```

How can I achieve this?

**Update:** Also, how can i exclude the parents that have certain attributes? For example, I need to exclude those that have data-anchor=2 and data-anchor=3 I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".parent").each(function(){
    $(this).after($(".child", this));
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/onsb12jx/

Note: `$(".child", this)` is just a shorter version of `$(this).find(".child")`

Excluding elements can use either `.not()` or `:not()` or a filter:

e.g. using `.not()`

```
$(".parent").not('[data-anchor=2],[data-anchor=3]').each(function(){
    $(this).after($(".child", this));
});
```

or using `:not` pseudo selector

```
$(".parent:not([data-anchor=2],[data-anchor=3])").each(function(){
    $(this).after($(".child", this));
});
```

or using a `filter()` function

```
$(".parent").filter(function(){
        return $(this).data('anchor') == "2" || $(this).data('anchor') == "3";
    }).each(function(){
    $(this).after($(".child", this));
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! I like this solution! Could you please help me: how could i exclude the parents that have certain attributes? For example, I need to exclude those that have data-anchor=2 and data-anchor=3
I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Dude, you are the best! The 'not' thing is beautiful! I had no idea about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by looping over the `.child` elements and using `insertAfter()` to place them after their closest parent `.parent` element:

```
$('.parent .child').each(function() {
    $(this).insertAfter($(this).closest('.parent'));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6pv2mnko/)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(".parent").each(function() {
  $(this).after($(this).find(".child"));
});
```

`after()` will help you to position the element after the selected element

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.after(fn)` method with a function as an argument to return the desired behavior, a benefit of it is not to use a loop explicitly, This way it will do this for you internally:

```js
$('.parent').after(function() {
  return $('.child', this);
});
```

```css
.parent{border:solid red 3px;}
.child{border:solid 3px green; margin:3px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child</div>
  parent
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child</div>
  parent
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child</div>
  parent
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `detach` method to do that like so:

```
$(".parent").each(function() {
  $(this).after($(this).find(".child").detach());
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ftej1m1k/)

You can check the structure by Inspecting element of the age :)

Comment: Detach has no effect here, as `after` will *move* the element in the DOM.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie But, isnt `after`supposed to just insert whatever its given without removing it first from dom? :o

Comment: No, it does not clone single elements (only when multiples are required). The end result is the same either way, the original is removed so detach is not needed here :P

Comment: Simple example here: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ftej1m1k/1/ If it was not removed you would have 4 of them :)